# Container decoration image bug in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage('assets/images/btn-img.png'),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
  ...
),
```

The bug is that the image of the container widget is misplaced (a little bottom relative to Container's position). Does anyone have experienced same problem?

**Update**

when I use another image with larger height, it works fine (My current image height is 302px)

**Update2**

The problem seems to be with color filter, when I disable color filter it works fine.

Comment: did you tried fit: BoxFit.fill, ?

Comment: run your app from the terminal: `flutter -v -d chrome run `, when the chrome browser appears type (in the terminal) `p` key and take a screenshot

Comment: It is also possible the png image itself has some empty space at the top, so the image might look misplaced a little towards the bottom.

Comment: @KhalifaAlkhatri yes I tried

Comment: @JigarPatel it works fine on android application

Comment: @AlirezaAbiri , pskink is right. Since it is a layout problem, a screenshot would help a lot. Otherwise we don't exactly see the problem.

Comment: i am facing this exact same issue where the color filter is not working on flutter web

Comment: I have the exact code and issue. Did you find a solution? It works fine on android and ios, but not in browser (Chrome). EDIT: BoxFit.fill does work for me. It looks like the image dimensions are improper for the web rendering.